# Check connection using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

How can I check the database connection using Entity Framework 6?

Here's my code:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseDataModel(connectionString))
{
    if (context.Database.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        return;

    if (!context.Database.Exists())
        return;

    context.Items.Add(item);        
}
```

How can I check if the connection is established before adding my items to the database? I can't open the connection because it will take plenty of time in case of corrupt connection string. That means my state check above is meaningless. The same concerns for the context.Database.Exist(), it will also take long time in case of corrupt connection string.

I aim to detect the corrupt connection string before doing any critical operation.

Comment: How would your connection string get corrupt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to *predict* if it is possible to connect to your database.  Well, this is not possible.  There is no way to know *if* you will connect *until* you try to.  Connection to the db may fail for various reasons:

1. DB Server is not responding, because SqlServer is down.
2. The server computer is down (power failure, for example).
3. The server you connect to does not exist.
4. The server exists, but you connect on wrong port.
5. The database refuses connection because you are not authorized.
6. The db server is busy and responds very slowly.
7. The network is bad / busy and data is transmitted very slowly.
8. The server is there, but configured in such a way that it refuses your connection.  For example, it wants TCP, but you try named pipes.

And many more.  It is absolutely impossible to validate against all these.